# How to Position an Image with A-HREF

Tags: html, css, href, positioning

My Code:

```
<div id="irc-banner">
            <a href="https://boltirc.net/" alt="irc-banner">
                <img src="images/BoltIRC.gif" alt="irc-banner">
            </a>
```

How would I select that image to position it around my screen in CSS? Thanks. Normally it works for me, but not this time... Weird..

Answer (score 1):

Well, just selecting the image would be something like this:

```
#irc-banner a img {
    /*DoSomething*/
}
```

But you could also assign an ID to the `img` tag and select it that way as well. You mentioned that normally it works for you, so you might already be using my code above, but possibly have a duplicate ID somewhere that is throwing your CSS off... Just a hunch though

Answer (score 0):

select the `img` tag with the `a` tag of the `#irc-banner` ID

```
#irc-banner a img{
   margin: 5px auto 7px auto; /*example*/
}
```